# Extracting text from image - OCR

Tags: python, image-processing, ocr, tesseract, python-tesseract

I'm using cv2 and pytesseract library to extract text from image. Here is the image (image3_3.png) and the python code:

[image]

```
def threshold_image(img_src):
    """Grayscale image and apply Otsu's threshold"""
    # Grayscale
    img_gray = cv2.cvtColor(img_src, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
    # Binarisation and Otsu's threshold
    img_thresh = cv2.threshold(img_gray, 0, 255, cv2.THRESH_BINARY + cv2.THRESH_OTSU)[1]
    return img_thresh

img = np.array(Image.open('image3_3.png'))
# Apply dilation and erosion to remove some noise
kernel = np.ones((1, 1), np.uint8)
img = cv2.dilate(img, kernel, iterations=1)
img = cv2.erode(img, kernel, iterations=1)

# normalise the image
norm_img = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1]))
img = cv2.normalize(img, norm_img, 0, 255, cv2.NORM_MINMAX)  
# Apply blur to smooth out the edges
img = cv2.GaussianBlur(img, (5, 5), 0)
string_ocr = pytesseract.image_to_string(threshold_image(img), lang = 'eng', config = '--psm 6')
print(string_ocr)
```

Here is the result:

```
Image A3. This is image A3 with more texts.

ISAS Visual Analytics

INow everyone can easily discover and share powerful
Nsights that inspire action
```

Why am I not getting the same exact text? Any help highly appreciated.

Comment: I think you need to invert your thresholded image so that the text is black on white background. Don't overblur either.

Comment: yes. the edges from the white background to the green background make it to the OCR, which tries to interpret those... as upper case `i` letters and whatnot. -- tesseract is really quite dumb. the fact that it requires preprocessing should make you shun it. there's better OCR out there.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz is there any way to get rid of the i's?

Comment: yes. you do image processing to grab those highlighted text lines *only*, treat them so they're accepted by tesseract (padding?) but the background/foreground is right.